# C# - Doubled data in ComboBox (SQLAnywhere connection)

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, wpf-controls, sqlanywhere

I write a Tool which has got a connection to a SQL Anywhere database via ConnectionString.
I want to receive some data and bind them to a ComboBox via Loaded Event.

`private void VesselNoComboBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ListShipNames();
        }`

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Receive all vessels from Database and add them to the combobox.
    /// A variable Database connection has to be built.
    /// </summary>
    private void ListShipNames()
    {
        SAConnection sqlCon = new SAConnection();
        sqlCon.ConnectionString = "Data Source=****; User id=****; Password=****";
        try
        {
            sqlCon.Open();
            SACommand cmd = new SACommand("Select ID || ' ' || NAME from test.SHIP_DATA", sqlCon);
            SADataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                VesselNoComboBox.Items.Add(reader.GetString(0));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error ", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Exclamation);
        }
        finally
        {
            sqlCon.Close();
        }
    }
```

In WPF the first ComboBox_Loaded will be executed when starting the program. And then when the UserControl will be loaded. So that all data will be doubled. An explicit `Clear()` would remove the ComboBox entries.
Could someone give me a hint?

Comment: Are you loading the control via a template or via code in an apply template?

Comment: No, I am loading the UserControl directly in my WPF Window. like: <code>xmlns:tabData="clr-namespace:xxx.UserControls"</code> and reference to it with <TabItem Header="UserControlName">
                    <tabData:xxxUserControl />
                </TabItem>

Answer (score 0):

Without further information regarding your solution, I cannot give you a reason why. I can tell you that the loaded event can be fired multiple times when the control is loaded from within a template. This is because the Loaded event is fired every time the control is included in a visual tree the reason can be infered from this [MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2006/09/19/loadedvsinitialized.aspx) by Mike Hillberg.

***NOTE:*** You may not know you are being loaded from a template. For example, a tab control treats each tab as a template, loading it when you click on the tab and unloading it when you move off. Philipp Sumi describes that problem [here](http://www.hardcodet.net/2008/01/wpf-loaded-event-fired-repeatedly).

The way around this is to ensure your data loading code is not in the control loading event.

A more WPF solution would be to use databinding. Instead of loaded the data and adding it directly to the control. To do this,

1. Set up a data context to your view model.
2. Populate an ObservableCollection, possibly in the constructor of your ViewModel.
3. Bind the ItemsSource property of the combobox to the collection.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the information! That was a good hint. I've tested it by explicitly clearing the ComboBox after the App is loaded. But I will change it to use ObservableCollection and I will bind the ItemsSource.